# Update list by another list (linq)

Tags: c#, linq

I have List of object of class "Data" that look like:

```
class Data
{
    int code;
    string name;
    ...
    DateTime date_update;
}
```

and I have another list of class, like:

```
class RefCodes
{
    int old_code;
    int new_code;
    string new_name;
    DateTime date_update;
}
```

The list of "Data" contains like 1,000 objects.
The list of "RefCodes" contains like 30 objects.

I need to replace in list "Data", 
the fields: 
"code" to be with value of "new_code",
and the "name" to be with value of "new_name".

The replacement need to be only for the objects that their code exist in list "RefCodes".
by the query: if code in `Data.code == RefCodes.old_code` 
How can I do it?

Comment: Are the `code`s a unique key for list `Data`?

Comment: What have you tried?  What issues did you run into?  You'll have more luck if you actually show some effort on your part to solve the problem.

Comment: no... it's unique only in "RefCodes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
foreach (var rcodeObj in RefCode)
{
     foreach(var obj in (Data.Where(t => t.code == rcodeObj.old_code)))
     {
        obj.code = rcodeObj.new_code;
        obj.name = rcodeObj.new_name;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C#6 you could use linq to do something like this

```
var updatedData = data.Select(x => new Data
{
   code = refCodes.FirstOrDefault(y => y.old_code == x.code)?.new_code ?? x.code,
   name = refCodes.FirstOrDefault(y => y.old_code == x.code)?.new_name ?? x.name,
});
```

Comment: Great oneliner. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
foreach (var x in DataList)
{
    var itemRefCode = RefCodesList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.old_code == x.code);
    if (itemRefCode != null)
    {
        x.code = itemRefCode.new_code;
        x.name = itemRefCode.new_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through each of the lists and update the values as follows. Here I am using some sample inputs as shown below. Note that I am considering the fields of the classes to be public, for simplicity:

```
List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>
{
    new Data { code = 1, name = "A" },
    new Data { code = 2, name = "B" },
    new Data { code = 10, name = "C" },
};
List<RefCodes> refList = new List<RefCodes>
{
    new RefCodes { old_code = 1, new_code = 11, new_name = "X" },
    new RefCodes { old_code = 2, new_code = 22, new_name = "Y" }
};

Console.WriteLine("Before");
dataList.ForEach(data => Console.WriteLine(data.code + ": " + data.name));
Console.WriteLine("");
```

Here is the code to do the updating:

```
foreach (var refCodes in refList)
{
    foreach (var data in dataList)
    {
        if (data.code == refCodes.old_code)
        {
            data.code = refCodes.new_code;
            data.name = refCodes.new_name;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("After");
dataList.ForEach(data => Console.WriteLine(data.code + ": " + data.name));
```

Output:

```
Before
1: A
2: B
10: C

After
11: X
22: Y
10: C
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [Left Outer Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397895.aspx).
For example,

```
IEnumerable<Data> query = from data in dataList
                          join refCode in refList on data.code equals refCode.old_code into joined
                          from subCode in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new Data
                          {
                              code = subCode?.new_code ?? data.code,
                              name = subCode?.new_name ?? data.name,
                              date_update = subCode == null ? data.date_update : DateTime.Now
                          };
```

will return a sequence with the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Would this solve your problem:

```
    public void Update( List<Data> data, List<RefCodes> refCodes )
    {
        List<RefCodes> differences = refCodes
            .Where( r => data.Any( d => r.old_code == d.code ) )
            .ToList();

        differences.ForEach( ( RefCodes item ) =>
         {
             Data element = data.FirstOrDefault( d => d.code == item.old_code );
             element.code = item.new_code;
             element.name = item.new_name;
         } );
    }
```

Comment: why i need to do: "data.FirstOrDefault"?

Answer (score 0):

---

> **Let say  tempAllocationR is list 1 and tempAllocationV is List2 **

---

```
var tempAllocation = new List<Object>();
    if (tempAllocationR.Count > 0 && tempAllocationV.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (TempAllocation tv in tempAllocationV)
                        {
                            var rec = tempAllocationR.FirstOrDefault(tr => tr.TERR_ID == tv.TERR_ID && tr.TERR == tv.TERR && tr.Team == tv.Team);
                            if (rec != null)
                            {
                                rec.Vyzulta = tv.Vyzulta;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                tempAllocationR.Add(tv);
                            }

                        }
                        tempAllocation = tempAllocationR;
                    }
                    else if (tempAllocationV.Count == 0 && tempAllocationR.Count > 0)
                    {
                        tempAllocation = tempAllocationR;
                    }
                    else if (tempAllocationR.Count == 0 && tempAllocationV.Count > 0)
                    {
                        tempAllocation = tempAllocationV;
                    }
```