# Linq join 2 different list with one commonality

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have two lists from two different tables, name can common in both, but second value has to remain unique. I want to throw them into one class list:

```
public class Selected
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Collected { get; set; }
    public bool Transferred { get; set; }
}

var collected = await (from nc in namescollected where parentid = id
                       select new Selected {Name = nc.Name, Collected = true}).ToListAsync();

var transferred = await (from nt in namestransferred where parentid = id
                         select new Selected {Name = nt.Name, Transferred = true}).ToListAsync();
```

I would like to combine them into one by taking the 2 lists:

Collected:

```
Name = NY, collected= true;
Name = NH, collected= true;
Name = NC, collected= true;
Name = FL, collected= true;
```

Transferred:

```
Name = NY, Transferred = true;
Name = VA, Transferred = true;
Name = CO, Transferred = true;
Name = FL, Transferred = true;
```

Merge into the list selected class:

```
Name = NY, Collected = true, Transferred = true;
Name = NH, collected= true, Transferred = false;
Name = NC, collected= true, Transferred = false;
Name = VA, collected= false, Transferred = true;
Name = CO, collected= false, Transferred = true;
Name = FL, collected= true, Transferred = true;
```

I can add the ones from the second list that are missing from first list:

```
var newItems = transferred.Where(x => !collected.Any(y => x.Name== y.Name));

foreach (var item in newItems)
{
    collected.Add(new Selected { Name = item.Name, Transferred = item.Transferred });
}
```

But that only adds the missing ones, I now need to go back through the list and make sure existing ones have the 'transferred' status assigned.

My brain is currently broken and this can probably be streamlined but I'm not seeing it right now.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does this work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#inner-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the brain kickstart.  This is what I ended up using to update the initial list after I added the missing ones, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41721120/15508225):

```
foreach (var transferredObj in transferred)
{
   foreach (var obj in (collected.Where(t => t.Name == transferredObj.Name)))
   {
       obj.Transfered = transferredObj.Transfered;
   }
}
```

So I ended keeping all my original code and adding the above  As @tstrand66 mentioned, it would be in my best interest to merge those 2 tables into one or create a view.  With that one change I could remove a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Enumerable.Join function. Checkout the MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Give the below fiddle a spin. It should at least get you started down a path that you can refactor for efficiency. Optimally you would join the tables in SQL and then just digest them. But sans that i would take my 2 different arrays and loop them shunting everything into a Dictionary. From there if you want an array just dump your dictionary values back to an array and you will have a unique array built on the guaranteed uniqueness of the Dictionary.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/E3jiec